# How do I decompose a discriminated union that is a type?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Suppose I have the following (basic and slightly pointless) F#...

```
type Point = Point of int * int
type MyUnion =
    | MyInt of int
    | MyString of string
    | MyTwoStrings of string * string
    | MyPoint of Point
```

...then I can write a function like this...

```
let MyUnionType myunion =
  match myunion with
  | MyInt n -> printfn "You gave me an Int (%d)" n
  | MyString s -> printfn "You gave me a string (%s)" s
  | MyTwoStrings (s1, s2) -> printfn "You gave me two strings (\"%s\", \"%s\")" s1 s2
  // Missing case here...
```

This works fine for the first three variations of `MyUnionType` but I can't work out how to write a clause to match when it is `MyPoint`

I tried the following, similar to the `MyTwoStrings` case...

```
| MyPoint (p1, p2) -> printfn "You gave me a point (%d, %d)" p1 p2
```

...but this gives a compiler error saying that `(p1, p2)` was expected to have type `Point` but has type `'a * 'b`

I tried the following...

```
| MyPoint p -> printfn "You gave me a point (%A)" p
```

..which works, but doesn't give me access to the two `int` values in the `Point`

How do I get at the two `int` values in the `Point`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`type Point = Point of int * int` is a single-case discriminated union, not just a tuple.

You construct it like `let p = Point(0, 0)`, so you need to deconstruct it in a similar way. Your last example is a good starting point: `| MyPoint p -> ...` binds the `Point` value to `p`, so you can later deconstruct it:

```
| MyPoint p ->
    let (Point (p1, p2)) = p
    printfn "You gave me a point (%i, %i)" p1 p2
```

or you can combine the deconstruction in the `match` itself:

```
| MyPoint (Point (p1, p2)) -> printfn "You gave me a point (%i, %i)" p1 p2
```

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense when you explain it! Thanks so much.

Comment: Your first answer is not quite right, you need extra parentheses to decompose a union case in a let: `let (Point (p1, p2)) = p`. What you wrote creates a local function called `Point` which takes a tuple as argument, ignores it and returns p.

Answer (score 5):

Your type `Point` is of exactly the same nature as your type `MyUnion`. The only difference is that `Point` has one constructor, but `MyUnion` has several. That's it.

The fact that the `Point`'s constructor has the same name as the type itself is completely irrelevant. Type names and constructor names are in different namespaces. They can be same or different, that changes nothing.

So, the way to get out the contents of your `Point` type would be exactly the same as with `MyUnion`, for example:

```
let sumCoords p = match p with
    | Point (x,y) = x + y
```

And then, this pattern can also be nested in another pattern:

```
let MyUnionType myunion =
      match myunion with
      | MyInt n -> printfn "You gave me an Int (%d)" n
      | MyString s -> printfn "You gave me a string (%s)" s
      | MyTwoStrings (s1, s2) -> printfn "You gave me two strings (\"%s\", \"%s\")" s1 s2
      | MyPoint (Point (x,y)) -> printfn "You gave me a point (%d, %d)" x y
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'd already accepted Honza's answer when yours came in, and as they are very similar, I'll leave his accepted, but I appreciate yours as well. All very useful

Comment: Sure, no problem. Honza managed to submit his answer while I was typing mine.

Comment: On the other hand, I like Fyodor's explanation with `match` more :) Deconstruction in `let` like in my answer is a bit of a special case itself, while `match` is consistent regardless of the number of constructors/cases of the discriminated union.